# UserControl for MonthCalendar

Tags: c#, user-controls, monthcalendar

I'm trying to modify monthcalendar, but before adding user control to the form, VS freezes. the problem is in an infinite loop, but I can't can find the error. Help, please

```
private void SetDayBoxSize()
{
  int bottom = this.Height;

  while (HitTest(1, dayTop).HitArea != HitArea.Date &&
         HitTest(1, dayTop).HitArea != HitArea.PrevMonthDate) dayTop++;

  while (HitTest(1, bottom).HitArea != HitArea.Date &&
    HitTest(1, bottom).HitArea != HitArea.NextMonthDate) bottom--;

  dayBox = new Rectangle();
  dayBox.Size = new Size(this.Width / 7, (bottom - dayTop) / 6);
}
```

Comment: We're going to need to see the HitTest code, since it's most likely something where `dayTop` and `bottom` aren't being calculated correctly to end the `while`. Possibly because one is going up, the other is going down.

Comment: @krillgar this is a [standard method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa335429(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: I think you should watch dayTop and bottom values to see what's happening. And also setting size using a while loop seems strange.

Comment: You can easily get Nowhere from the hittest and that will hang your loop.  Using 1 is not a happy choice.  Then again, there are no happy choices.  Ask another question, this time explaining what you want to accomplish and why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to fix the issue:

```
private void SetDayBoxSize()
{
  int bottom = this.Height;

  while (HitTest(25, dayTop).HitArea != HitArea.Date &&
         HitTest(25, dayTop).HitArea != HitArea.PrevMonthDate) dayTop++;

  while (HitTest(25, bottom).HitArea != HitArea.Date &&
    HitTest(25, bottom).HitArea != HitArea.NextMonthDate) bottom--;

  dayBox = new Rectangle();
  dayBox.Size = new Size(this.Width / 7, (bottom - dayTop) / 6);
}
```